# keycloak log analysis: is there a built-in functionality?

Tags: keycloak

I'd like to understand if in keycloak (KL) is possible to analyze authentication log (number of tries, errors, ...), if KL already provides something to do that, or I must to build it.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you
Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keycloak allows you to activate event and audit logging into its database.
See [Keycloak documentation on Auditing and Events](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#auditing-and-events).

Answer (score 3):

Keycloak provides a rich set of auditing capabilities. Every single login action can be recorded and stored in the database and reviewed in the Admin Console. All admin actions can also be recorded and reviewed. There is also a Listener SPI with which plugins can listen for these events and perform some action. Built-in listeners include a simple log file and the ability to send an email if an event occurs.

You can enable and view logs through the admin console of the Keycloak. For more information refer to [Keycloak Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/6.0/server_admin/#auditing-and-events)

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak's log can also be processed by (http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)[Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)